# Can Elderberries "beat the flu, prevent colds, and strengthen your immunity"?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, alternative-medicine

According to http://realfarmacy.com/diy-flu-syrup/, "Elderberry Beats the Flu, Prevents Colds, and Strengthens Your Immunity." As with all dietary advice I find on the internet, I'm hesitant to believe this claim (and I'd be very surprised if the claim wasn't at least overhyped). Does Elderberry really have the claim properties?

Comment: One thing I noticed is in the abstract of the cited research - "Symptoms were relieved on average 4 days earlier and use of rescue medication was significantly less in those receiving elderberry extract compared with placebo... These findings need to be confirmed in a larger study." - on one hand 4 days is a HUGE difference that makes it sound implausible, but mentioning that a larger study is needed does make it sound slightly more plausible. Has a larger study been done?

Comment: I would like to see the answer to this, because it's something my mother always used to say. She also used to cook up elderberry syrup and feed it to us.

Comment: Found some useful links - https://www.superfoodly.com/does-sambucol-black-elderberry-really-work-for-colds-flu/ and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28198157. I'll turn them into an answer if nobody else does before I get off work.

Answer (score 4):

## There is limited research on the treatment of Elderberries.

However, It is officially listed as a treatment option by NCBI

Note: The presence of this link is evidence of notability rather than effectiveness.

- [National Center for Biotechnology Information which is part of the
  United States National Library of Medicine
  lists:](https://medlineplus.gov/flu.html#cat_78)

  > Treatments and Therapies:
  >
  > European Elder (Elderberry)

NCBI then links elderberries to the [National Center for Complementary and Integrative Health](https://nccih.nih.gov/health/euroelder)

- > Although some preliminary research indicates that elderberry may
  > relieve flu symptoms, **the evidence is not strong enough to support its
  > use for this purpose.**
- > Researchers funded by the National Center for Complementary and
  > Integrative Health (NCCIH) are studying the antioxidant effects of
  > extracts from elderberry and their possible relevance to the body’s
  > defense against infection.

Citation from realfarmacy.com :

- [Study listed by (NCBI) National Center for Biotechnology Information](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15080016)

  A study published by [Department of Virology, Hebrew
  University-Hadassah Medical School, Jerusalem, Israel.](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/147323000403200205?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori:rid:crossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3dpubmed)

  > Randomized study of the efficacy and safety of oral elderberry extract
  > in the treatment of influenza A and B virus infections.
  >
  > Patients received 15 ml of elderberry or placebo syrup four times a
  > day for 5 days, and recorded their symptoms using a visual analogue
  > scale. Symptoms were relieved on average 4 days earlier and use of
  > rescue medication was significantly less in those receiving elderberry
  > extract compared with placebo. Elderberry extract seems to offer an
  > efficient, safe and cost-effective treatment for influenza. These
  > findings need to be confirmed in a larger study.

---

There is not enough research to substantiate these claims.

Comment: Echinacea is also listed as a treatment option, but if you follow a couple links down (https://nccih.nih.gov/health/tips/flucold.htm) it says "Echinacea has not been proven to help prevent or treat colds" - so it appears that the list is not treatments that have been proven to work. Also, that study is cited by "realfarmacy" and is rather suspect to me - it's a small study of 60 people, and it's the product they use (Sambucol) was developed by someone from their same university. Doesn't invalidate the study, but does make it suspect.

Comment: @RobWatts I believe anything written or cited by *realfarmacy* is pure fluff. But anything published by NCBI is legit. I don't see what Echinacea not being proven to help or prevent colds has to do with anything. Not to get more off topic but I do drink tea with Echinacea when my throat hurts and it definitely immediately relieves irritation, however it definitely doesn't cure anything.

Comment: NCBI didn't publish it - they've just included it in their index of research.

Comment: @RobWatts [Department of Virology, Hebrew University-Hadassah Medical School, Jerusalem, Israel.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15080016)

Seems pretty legit to me, what's your problem with it?

Comment: @RobWatts Did you even look at the [references](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/147323000403200205?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori:rid:crossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3dpubmed) used by Hadassah Medical School?

Comment: As I mentioned, the study uses Sambucol, which was created by a professor at that university. That indicates to me that the people who did the study are somewhat likely to have a vested interest in the product succeeding (it could be something like wanting to increase their university's prestige or knowing the professor will help make sure their paper gets published), which can bias a study even when they're trying to be neutral.

Comment: @RobWatts Surely bias exists in any study. However, he seems to be pretty respected in his field. Adding to credibility is the NCBI which is pretty picky about what they add. I'm sure if they believed there to be an issue of bias they wouldn't post it at all. They aren't the type of organization to EX: put homeopathic nonsense up as fact.

Comment: @RobWatts if you look at Hadassah Medical School's citations you can see that it's not just their research. For example: https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/cpb1958/38/5/38_5_1329/_article 
Unless there's collusion with japan or something.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on that "European Elder (Elderberry)" link? (Here, try it. [European Elder (Elderberry)](https://nccih.nih.gov/health/euroelder)) Particularly note the "What Have We Learned?" section. It's clear NCBI isn't saying "use elderberry"; it's simply linking to a site describing the stuff, presumably for people who have heard it was good for the flu and were doing their due diligence.

Comment: @cHao That's a good point. But I find it odd that the US National Library of Medicine actually lists it as a treatment option which seems to contradict U.S. Department of Health & Human Services "actions of individual ingredients are unclear." So I'm not sure what to take from that. To US Gov organizations with different views?

Comment: They *don't* "actually list it as a treatment option". They simply include it in a list of  remedies that people have probably heard of. That implies that it's a common enough folk remedy to be mentioned, not that it actually works.

Comment: @cHao It's listed right next to over the counter decongestant. Is that a folk remedy too? I'm not saying that elderberries cure or treat anything. But it's listed right there under treatments so NCBI thinks so

Comment: No, it's a remedy common enough to be notable. Note, OTC remedies don't "beat the flu" or "prevent colds" either. They only treat symptoms.

Comment: @cHao right it's under treatments. I never said it cured anything

Comment: @cHao How's this answer look now?

Comment: But you're implying, by including it in your answer to this particular question, that it's inclusion in the list constitutes some kind of claim of effectiveness.

Comment: @cHao I'm just saying that's how it's listed there on their website now. I'm saying that there's not enough research to full say it's a cure or not. Is that fine?

Comment: The implication is still there. If you want to keep the list quote, I'd suggest you (1) actually make it a link to the elderberry page, and (2) be more explicit that the presence of that link is evidence of notability rather than effectiveness.

Comment: @cHao I added (2) that but I don't see what's wrong with my link? It does link to elderberry

Comment: Right now it's not even a link. What i'm suggesting is that "European Elder (Elderberry)" link to https://nccih.nih.gov/health/euroelder the way it does on the flu page.

Comment: @cHao I've added the elderberry link from National Center for Complementary and Integrative Health

Comment: Looks better :)

Comment: I've changed your conclusion as in medicine the "null hypothesis", the default option we take on something we don't know, is that of the plant being useless. Thus, a lack of research should be summarized as "there's no evidence to say it's effective", not "there's some credibility". In fact, lack of research points exactly in the opposite direction: no one is experimenting on it because no one thinks it's effective enough.